# I can't get an integer from my Python sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite3-python

I want to get the integer 5 from my database but I keep getting "[('5',)]" or "('5',)" this is my code:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
cursor = db.cursor()

def get_clearance(username='CC-2225', clearance=None):
        find_clearance = "SELECT clearance FROM user WHERE username = username"
        cursor.execute(find_clearance)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        return results

print(get_clearance())
```

Comment: Is `clearance` an integer in your database ?

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list of rows, and each row is a tuple of values.  So that explains the `[( )]` part.

Comment: @JohnGordon and connector doesn't know type of colums so it's always a string

Comment: `WHERE username = username` looks like a good way of getting all rows with a non-NULL username...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not uncommon for database API to return list or tuples.

A simple solution would be to cast this value directly to integer, if you are sure it will always be an integer:

For the list of tuples ("[('5',)]"):

```
return int(results[0][0])
```

For the tuple ("('5',)"):

```
return int(results[0])
```